# Remove part of the url and redirect it to a new url without overlapping old one

Tags: symfony

I have a symfony application that I want to redirect old url `katalog/maedchen/` to be without katalog like this `/maedchen/`.

I used the following code to do that

```
catalog_gender_redirect:
  path: /katalog/{gender}
  defaults:
    _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect
    route: item_catalog_gender
    permanent: true

catalog_gender:
  path: /{gender}
  defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Catalog:show", _locale: de }
  methods: [GET]
```

but the problem that url match another base uri which is,

```
catalog_brand:
  path: /{marke}
```

so the redirection goes to this url instead of the one I wanted to go to, I don't want to move it offcourse to the top cause it will overwrite my current redirected route, how to differentiate between the two routes and what the proper way to do that in symfony? ( redirecting the old url to a new one without missing with the current structure ?

Answer (score 0):

Just put requirements to {gender} like:

```
requirements: ‘maedchen|man’
```

Also put the route above the one for the brands, because in Symfony first match wins.

Comment: can I have this requirements dynamic ? may be from the database as array ?

Comment: Yes, you can, but is quite kinky. Basically you will need to create your own dynamic router which holds the routing collection